# how to retrieve the value of a string column with slick?

Tags: database, scala, slick

I can't find a string result contained in a column...

here is the table:

```
object Equivalences extends Table[(Option[Int], String, String)]("EQUIVALENCES") {

    def id = column[Int]("EQV_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def racine = column[String]("RAC")

    def definition = column[String]("DEF")

    def * = id.? ~ racine ~ definition

}
```

and here is the wrong code:

```
def ajoute_si_racine_absente(racine_ajoutée: String, definition_ajoutée: String) = {
    val cul = Query(Equivalences).filter( 
        equ => {
            println(equ.racine)
            equ.racine.toString.contains(racine_ajoutée)
        })
    if (cul.list().length == 0) {
        Equivalences.insert(None, racine_ajoutée, definition_ajoutée)
    }
}
```

the wrong code aims to insert a value if it does not exists, but the "println" within displays this result: "(EQUIVALENCES @409303125).RAC" and it does not match the column's content.
Maybe should I use the "getResult" method but I did not found any example on the net.

thanks.

Comment: `equ.racine` is a column, you shouldn't want to print it. 

`filter` is not executing on all the rows in the table, it constructs a query that gets executed on the database side when you call `cul.list()`; the body is run exactly once. 

`equ.racine.toString` is a string (a single string equal to `"(EQUIVALENCES @409303125).RAC"`) and you don't need it. 

Try `val cul = Query(Equivalences).filter(equ => equ.racine.like('%'+racine_ajoutée+'%'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karol S is right. This does what you want:

```
def ajoute_si_racine_absente(racine_ajoutée: String, definition_ajoutée: String) = {
    val cul = Query(Equivalences).list().filter( 
        equ => {
            println(equ.racine)
            equ.racine.toString.contains(racine_ajoutée)
        })
    if (cul.length == 0) {
        Equivalences.insert(None, racine_ajoutée, definition_ajoutée)
    }
}
```

But it may not be efficient, because you fetch the complete table. Slick is a query builder with a collection like API. Everything you write just resembles and builds up a query description until you finally call `.list`or `.run`. Only then the query is executed. Everything before are just placeholder objects representing tables, queries and columns. And the placeholder object for column racine prints as `"(EQUIVALENCES @409303125).RAC"`.